# Wrap C++ code with cython (with templates)

Tags: c++, templates, cython

I'm trying to create a cython wrapper from C++ code (it just adds two numbers).
I have the following code:

myc.cpp:

```
#include "myc.hpp"

template <class T>
T add(T a,T b){
    return a+b;
}
```

myc.hpp:

```
template <class T>
T add(T a,T b);
```

myc.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "myc.hpp":
    T add[T](T a,T b)
```

mymodule.pyx:

```
# distutils: libraries = myc
# distutils: library_dirs = "."
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = myc.cpp

from myc cimport add

cpdef double add2(double a,double b):
    return add(a,b)
```

main.py:

```
from mymodule import add2

a = 32.0

print(add2(a,a))
```

The files are all in the same folder.
Now, if instead of using templates in the 'add' function definition, I use double type, the code works fine. If I change the 'from "myc.hpp":' from the myc.pxd file to 'from "myc.cpp":', the code works fine too.
So, why doesn't it work when I define the function from the header file in the myc.pxd?

PS: I call `cythonize -i mymodule.pyx`, and the following error appears at the end of the output:

> mymodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl add(double,double)" (??$add@N@@YANNN@Z)
> C:\Users\######\Desktop\#######\mymodule.cp37-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

Comment: This is really just a fairly basic C++ problem. The definition of a C++ template has to be visible to the compiler at the point you need it, hence it has to be defined in the header. (As an alternative you could explicitly request `add<double>` to be defined in the C++ file, but that's a little more tedious and usually not what you want)

Comment: It is already defined in the header file.

Comment: I understand it now :) thanks